# Using ONNX model in C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, faster-rcnn, onnx, onnxruntime

I have trained a deep learning model of Mask RCNN in Keras and have derived a ONNX model (weight matrix) which is able to run and test images in Python successfully. Is there any possibility to use the same ONNX model in Windows form Application, C# through Visual Studio? If yes, what would be the requirements?

System information:

- Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB
- Visual Studio 2019
- ONNX Runtime version (you are using):
- Mask RCNN, in ONNX Runtime v0.5.0

Answer (score 1):

ONNX Runtime is available from Nuget in the [Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime/) package. It supports .Net Standard 1.1 which means it can be used with .Net Framework 4.5 and newer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [CSharp API documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/master/docs/CSharp_API.md) which includes a complete Inference tutorial. If you want to run the onnx model on GPU make sure to have CUDA and cuDNN installed and added to the PATH.